# Display file icons in ranger inside spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, ranger

I am looking to get visual representation of different file extensions as discussed in this question.

> https://github.com/ranger/ranger/issues/298

In the question however there are some python files involved and the discussion is about the icon addon as a vim plugin.

I have the ranger as a spacemacs layer, so I would need to get it to work in spacemacs. Could someone please provide an easy guide (if it is possible at all) what to do to get some beautiful file icons for the files displayed in ranger in spacemacs instead of only text. Your help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Icons in Emacs are provided by the `all-the-icons` package. I believe that is installed in Spacemacs by default. You can run `M-x all-the-icons-install-fonts` to get the necessary fonts/glyphs for displaying the file icons and such.

It looks like ranger is an extension for `dired-mode` and there is an additional package [all-the-icons-dired](https://github.com/jtbm37/all-the-icons-dired) that adds support for dired-mode icons. You'll want to add that package to your `dotspacemacs-additional-packages` list to install it, and add this line to your `user-config` section:

```
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'all-the-icons-dired-mode)
```

Comment: This is awesome, seems to work at least in Ubuntu. One should first add the package though and then the option `all-the-icons-install-fonts` will appear.